# How do I size a popover to the size of the contentview?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uipopover

I have a popover which shows a UIViewController containing a UIView and a UILabel.
I want the popover to grow/shrink to the size of the content of the UILabel.
How do I do that? Here is the part of the UIViewController in the popover which now determines it's size...

```
#pragma mark - View controller life cycle

- (CGSize)preferredContentSize {
    return self.view.frame.size;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    _personNameLabel.text = self.person.fullNameWithTitle;
}
```

What do I need to do to have the popover to show the person's name and size itself to the size of the name?

Comment: calculate width and height and set this `self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(width,height);`//for iOS 6 for `iOS7` use this     `self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(width,height);` set this in `viewDidLoad` or in `viewWillAppear` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate width and height and set this,

For iOS 6,

```
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(width,height);
```

For iOS7,

```
self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(width,height);
```

set this in `viewDidLoad` or in `viewWillAppear` method.